# xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: junk after document element

Tags: python-2.7, jenkins

I get an error when I build a project in Jenkins,it seems like the python has some problems,but I don't know how to deal with it. anyone can help me?

The error looks like follows:

[image]

The last part reads:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 558, in feed self._parser.Parse(data, 0)
xml.parsers.ExpatError: junk after document elelment: line 1, column 91
```

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11656721/6309), check the xml file being parsed: if it starts with \n or anything else than `<?xml version="1.0"?>`, that would explain the error message.

This is an error often seen with Wordpress plugins: see for instance [`maxcutler/python-wordpress-xmlrpc` issue 28](https://github.com/https://github.com/maxcutler/python-wordpress-xmlrpc/issues/28#issuecomment-15675853)